# How to do sum and filter in rbind function

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, lapply, rbind

I am using an R package which extracts data from tables in a database based on the flag for each table. If the flag is `1`, extract data from that table. If the flag is `0`, don't extract data.

The extracted data is stored in the `person_list_df` list as shown below

```
list(structure(list(person_id = 21:25, count = 2:6), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L)), structure(list(person_id = 24:28, count = 3:7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L)))
```

Code is below

```
 person_list_df = list()
 casesANDcontrols_df = list()
 list1 <- data.frame("person_id" = 21:25, "count" = 2:6)
 list2 <- data.frame("person_id" = 24:28, "count" = 3:7)
 person_list_df <- list(list1, list2)
```

What I would like to do is

a) Combine/Merge all this and get the sum of counts (for each person)

b) Filter and store only persons who have count > 4

I tried the below but it doesn't work

```
casesANDcontrols_df[[1]] <- do.call(rbind, persons_list_df) # how to sum and apply filter here?
```

I would like to combine/merge all of them and sum their counts and finally select persons who have count > 4

I expect my output to be like as shown below

```
casesANDcontrols_df[[1]]

        person_id
    1   24        #COUNT IS 8
    2   25        #COUNT IS 10
    3   26        #COUNT IS 5
    4   27        #COUNT IS 6
    5   28        #COUNT IS 7
```

The structure of `caseANDcontrols_df` should be as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In base R, you can combine the list into one dataframe with `do.call` +`rbind`, take `sum` for each `person_id` and keep rows where `count` is greater than 4.

```
subset(aggregate(count ~ person_id, do.call(rbind, person_list_df), sum), count > 4)
```

Comment: I get an error like as below `Error in model.frame.default(formula = count ~ person_id, data = do.call(rbind,  : 
  object is not a matrix` when I try to execute the code suggested

Comment: @TheGreat Can you provide your data using `dput` which will help debug the issue.

Comment: Hi Ronak, I would like to create list of lists (with two columns) as shown above in my sample data. However am not able to create. Am trying to create now. few mins please. I need your help

Comment: Hi Ronak, I provided sample data with dput statement. can help me, please. In the output, I would like to see only one column which is `person_id`. I want `person_id` to be assigned to `casesANDcontrols_df[[1]]`.

Comment: `casesANDcontrols_df` is also an empty list which was defined initially

Comment: This seems to work : `casesANDcontrols_df[[1]] <- subset(aggregate(count~person_id, do.call(rbind,person_list_df), sum),count > 4, select = person_id)`. If you have already defined `casesANDcontrols_df = list()`

Comment: Please see the updated screenshot at the bottom of the post. Sure, I will try once again...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `rbindlist` funciton from `data.table`, which output a `data.table`, so you can chain:

```
bindeddf <- rbindlist(persons_list_df)[,.(count = sum(count)),by = person_id]
bindeddf[count>4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(persons_list_df) %>%
     group_by(person_id) %>%
     summarise(count = sum(count)) %>%
     filter(count > 4)
```

Comment: @TheGreat Sure, let me check that

Comment: I had error like as shown below when I tried the suggested solution, `Error: Problem with summarise() input count.
x invalid 'type' (closure) of argument
i Input `count` is `sum(count)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: person_id = 53558.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`